# Selenium WebDriver - Java. Please help selecting item from list by?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is an example of the html.  The application is like this for all the "dropdowns".  You click it then the options appear.  I want to be able to create this method and in a separate class be able to call the method be able to just call it (chooseState("California");) and pass the *state* variable and it choose the state.

```
<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" id="InputModel_State_listbox" aria-live="off" style="overflow: auto;">
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" id="InputModel_State_option_selected" aria-selected="true">--- select ---</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item"/>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">statename1</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">statename2</li>
    <li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item">statename50</li>
</ul>
```

Here is an example of the method I am trying to create which will allow you to grab the state name by the state variable

```
public void chooseState(String state) {
        try {


                         //This clicks the "Dropdown
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(State)).click();

                        //I need the Method to choose by state name.  I know I am sort of on the right track because I am able to click the first item I just need to be able to pass any state and it choose the correct one.

                        **Here are examples of things that failed**

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(State)).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText(state))).click();

Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By
                .id("InputModel_State_listbox")));
        select.deselectAll();
        select.selectByVisibleText("state");

Select select = new Select(findElement(by));
select.selectByVisibleText(state); }




        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            log.error("Fail ", e);
            Assert.fail();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to know the locator/identifer to click on the particular state name of the li items.

you can use XPath for this instead of cssSelector() as below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//li[text()='" + State + "']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Purus.  This worked.  So theoretically if I have other list like this in the app I can just do this 
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//li[text()='" + <VARIABLE> + "']")).click();

Comment: Yes. Xpath has more flexibility but might be slow in IE.

Comment: In Chrome and Firefox it will allow me to choose any state but in IE it will only let me choose what is showing when I click the dropdown which is the first 5 states.  Another reason to not like IE...
Thanks for your help Purus!